# Error when using overcommit and Github Desktop

Tags: ruby, github, rvm

I am using overcommit gem (https://github.com/brigade/overcommit) in my project, when I use Github Desktop for osx I get these errors:

> This repository contains hooks installed by Overcommit, but the
>   `overcommit` gem is not installed. Install it with `gem install
>   overcommit`.  (1)

The gem is installed, it works in terminal. I guess it's because I use rvm and Github Desktop doesn't know about rvm. Anybody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok finally got it to work!
Combined the answer from @michelegera with comment from @rewritten

Step 1:

```
sudo su -
gem install bundler
gem install overcommit
gem install rubocop
```

Step 2: added `command: ['bundle', 'exec', 'rubocop']` to `.overcommit.yml`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Same situation with Git Tower. The above didn't work for me until I launched Tower from Terminal using their CLI tools. I imagine GitHub for Desktop would have the same. https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/faq-and-tips/faq/hook-scripts

Comment: also fixes similar issue in SourceTree on Mac. thanks!

Comment: If you are curious about: `sudo su -` goto: https://superuser.com/a/105369

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's [this line](https://github.com/brigade/overcommit/blob/338a3602fcc8c6ffe16c8b458505985e5bebc9d5/template-dir/hooks/overcommit-hook#L53) where the error occurs. As you can see the main issue is that it's not able to `require 'overcommit'`. I don't know the GitHub desktop client so well (maybe there is a way to configure it inside of it), but one thing you could do is adding the absolute path  where rvm stores your gems to the "require path" in the hook file. This could look like:

```
$: << "/home/user/.rvm/path/to/gems/dir"
```

The disadvantage of this is that you would have your absolute path in the hook file and it most likely won't work for others. You might also want to consider installing the gem globally for the the ruby interpreter that executes the script (see Shebang line in the hook file).

Comment: thanks for your answer, so I installed overcommit globally. Now it cannot find rubocop (thats what I run in de pre-commit hook). So thats the next step.

Comment: @Chris use `command: ['bundle', 'exec', 'rubocop']` in the overcommit configuration so rubocop is run from inside the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Github Desktop (or any other GUI) isn’t running in your terminal environment, so it knows nothing about your specific RVM installation.

A simple solution is to install `overcommit` and any other gems required by your hooks into your system Ruby:

```
sudo su -
gem install bundler
gem install overcommit
gem install rubocop
...
```

If you installed Git via Homebrew or other means, you might have to change the **Git binary** used by your GUI.

For example, in [Tower](https://www.git-tower.com/), I selected Homebrew’s version rather than the System’s.

[image: Tower for OS X Git Config]

Comment: No luck:  `[RuboCop] FAILED
'rubocop' is not installed, not in your PATH, or does not have execute permissions
Install it by running: gem install rubocop`